# MEAN: Unhandled rejection MongoError: not authorized on mean-dev to execute command

Tags: node.js, mongodb, npm, meanjs

I installed **[meanjs](https://github.com/meanjs/mean/)** in my OpenSUSE distro, however when I run `npm start`, here's what I get:

```
+ Important warning: config.domain is empty. It should be set to the fully qualified domain of the app.
Unhandled rejection MongoError: not authorized on mean-dev to execute command { listIndexes: "sessions", cursor: {} }
    at Function.MongoError.create (/home/tasher/Projects/meanjs_test/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/error.js:31:11)
    at queryCallback (/home/tasher/Projects/meanjs_test/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/cursor.js:212:36)
    at /home/tasher/Projects/meanjs_test/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:469:18
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:73:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)
From previous event:
    at MongoStore.setAutoRemoveAsync (/home/tasher/Projects/meanjs_test/node_modules/connect-mongo/src/index.js:129:40)
    at MongoStore.handleNewConnectionAsync (/home/tasher/Projects/meanjs_test/node_modules/connect-mongo/src/index.js:121:18)
    at MongoStore (/home/tasher/Projects/meanjs_test/node_modules/connect-mongo/src/index.js:96:26)
    at Object.module.exports.initSession (/home/tasher/Projects/meanjs_test/config/lib/express.js:120:12)
    at Object.module.exports.init (/home/tasher/Projects/meanjs_test/config/lib/express.js:243:8)
    at /home/tasher/Projects/meanjs_test/config/lib/app.js:25:23
    at /home/tasher/Projects/meanjs_test/config/lib/mongoose.js:35:21
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:109:7)

Unhandled rejection MongoError: not authorized on mean-dev to execute command { listIndexes: "sessions", cursor: {} }
    at Function.MongoError.create (/home/tasher/Projects/meanjs_test/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/error.js:31:11)
    at queryCallback (/home/tasher/Projects/meanjs_test/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/cursor.js:212:36)
    at /home/tasher/Projects/meanjs_test/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:469:18
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:73:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)
From previous event:
    at MongoStore.setAutoRemoveAsync (/home/tasher/Projects/meanjs_test/node_modules/connect-mongo/src/index.js:129:40)
    at MongoStore.handleNewConnectionAsync (/home/tasher/Projects/meanjs_test/node_modules/connect-mongo/src/index.js:121:18)
    at MongoStore (/home/tasher/Projects/meanjs_test/node_modules/connect-mongo/src/index.js:96:26)
    at module.exports (/home/tasher/Projects/meanjs_test/config/lib/socket.io.js:73:20)
    at Object.module.exports.configureSocketIO (/home/tasher/Projects/meanjs_test/config/lib/express.js:214:38)
    at Object.module.exports.init (/home/tasher/Projects/meanjs_test/config/lib/express.js:258:14)
    at /home/tasher/Projects/meanjs_test/config/lib/app.js:25:23
    at /home/tasher/Projects/meanjs_test/config/lib/mongoose.js:35:21
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:109:7)

error: uncaughtException: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND linux-hcjz.suse date=Mon Aug 28 2017 22:46:50 GMT+0100 (WEST), pid=4497, uid=1000, gid=100, cwd=/home/tasher/Projects/meanjs_test, execPath=/usr/bin/node6, version=v6.11.1, argv=[/usr/bin/node6, /home/tasher/Projects/meanjs_test/server.js], rss=97284096, heapTotal=69029888, heapUsed=48863040, external=20182576, loadavg=[0.6513671875, 0.61669921875, 0.43505859375], uptime=3056
Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND linux-hcjz.suse
    at errnoException (dns.js:28:10)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:76:26)
```

I have re-installed **meanjs** twice but in vain. Mongo is also running. By the way:

```
tasher@linux-hcjz:~/Projects/meanjs_test> node -v
v6.11.1
tasher@linux-hcjz:~/Projects/meanjs_test> npm6 -v
3.10.10
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: The MongoDB errors are because you're not authorized on the database to run commands. By default to connection string MEAN uses is `mongodb://localhost/mean-dev`. If auth is enabled on your local mongod, you'll need to change your connection string to include a username and password. See here for more info: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/enable-authentication/

The other option is disabling auth on your local mongod (that should only be done if you're only using your local database for development).

Answer (score 0):

try adding execution permission to your mean-dev

```
chmod 755 path_for_package/mean-dev
```

replace path path_for_package with your path

Comment: What do you exactly mean by path_for_package? Path to what?

Comment: the location of your `bin/mean-dev` installation

Comment: can't find any `mean-dev` folder